# Animate hamburgerCSS when you close MaterializeCSS sidenav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using hamburger css https://jonsuh.com/hamburgers/ as my hamburger menu in my site. The open and close animations work fine and it opens/closes the materializecss sidenav properly.

However the sidenav has functionality where it closes when you click anywhere on the page, not just the hamburger icon. How can I trigger the hamburger css icon to animate closed when the sidenav menu is also closed?

I cannot find a state where the sidenav is closed. I believe the best way is to find the state of the sidenav and then trigger the toggleClass on the hamburgerCSS to do the close animation.

jquery to initialize sidenav and hamburgercss

```
Template.Top_navbar.onRendered(function () {    
('.button-collapse').sideNav(
            {
                edge: 'right',
                closeOnClick: true,
                draggable: true // Choose whether you can drag to open on touch screens
            }
        );
        $(".hamburger").on("click", function (e) {
            $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active");
            // Do something else, like open/close menu
        });
}
```

HTML of top bar which contains hamburger css icon

```
<template name="Top_navbar">
    <nav class="main-nav dm-gray base " role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper p-l-20 p-r-20">
            <a id="logo-container" href="/" class="left dm-logo hide-on-small-only"></a>
            <a id="logo-container-small-screen" href="/" class="left hide-on-med-and-up"></a>
            <span class="page-title-content p-l-20 m-l-20 m-t-20 left">{{ pageTitle }}</span>
            <button data-activates="nav-mobile" class="hamburger hamburger--squeeze show-on-large button-collapse sidebar-btn right" type="button">
              <span class="hamburger-box">
                <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
              </span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>
```

MaterializeCSS Side-Nav info http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html

**UPDATE**

So I couldn't find where MaterializeCSS was triggering the close of the side-nav. So for now I just used this solution:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
        if($hamburger.hasClass("is-active")){
            $hamburger.removeClass("is-active");
        }
    });
```

I know it's not the prettiest or most efficient solution. If I find something better I will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the line `2528 — 2530` of the materialize unminified javascript:

> $elem.sideNav(`'hide'`):
>
> > hide: function(){
> >         $(`"#sidenav-overlay"`).trigger(`'click'`);
> >     }

The `#sidenav-overlay` will be clicked if it clicked by user or triggered by $elem.sideNav(`'hide'`).
So the answer is binding a click handler to `#sidenav-overlay` after page load and side nav initialization like this:

```
$('.button-collapse').click(function(){
    $('.hamburger').addClass('is-active');
});
$('.sidenav-overlay').click(function(){
    $('.hamburger').removeClass('is-active');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply added
`$('#hamburger').removeClass('is-active');`
After line 2242 of unminified JS
and
`$('#hamburger').addClass('is-active');`
After line 2644

Not very clean, but very easy, and working fine.